# Flutter Basic Information

Tags: flutter

Following are the question which needs to be answered?

1.How to set inset border in Flutter.(already tried Border() but no inset option)

2.How to remove Material statelesswidget from index class. I know that stateful widget and stateless widget both are in the material library.but I need another way through which I can display normal layout without using the stateless or stateful widget.

3.Currently, Flutter doesn't support SVG. is there any other way to put SVG in the layout.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. In short, questions should be specific. Avoid asking multiple questions together

Answer (score -1):

I realize this isn't the best question - in the future try to ask 3 separate questions... but I'm going to answer it as best I can anyways.

1) I'm assuming you mean you want to inset your inner class. There are a few ways to do this, but the easiest is probably to use a container. This shows the inset types (similar-ish to how it works in HTML):

```
new Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
    border: new Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent)
  ),
  child: ...,
)
```

2) I don't really understand the question. You don't technically need Stateful & Stateless widgets to be able to make a flutter app - you can simply return a cascade of objects from runApp in your main function... but if you want to display any data or basically do anything, you need to define your own widgets.

The provided widgets are the basic building blocks of a flutter application; they contain logic for layout and rendering in their implementations, whereas your own widgets can almost exclusively use the provided widgets rather than having to understand how that all works. But to keep track of your app's state, you need stateful widgets, and to encapsulate a set of widgets a stateful widget helps a lot! You generally end up with a very nested structure in flutter (which it is optimized for) - a different paradigm from some other frameworks and languages that instead use XML or a structure markup language - but using stateless widgets can help to keep the nesting to a reasonable size.

I highly recommend following the [flutter codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter/index.html#0) and the other tutorials etc on the flutter.io website as they will show you the basics.

3) Unfortunately, flutter doesn't support SVGs at the moment although there is some discussion [on github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/1831) about supporting them in the future.

I've utilized some vectors in my project by using a CustomPainter + canvas and converting the path/circle/lines to drawCircle, drawPath, drawLine. I've a semi-automated tool for doing that but it's pretty hacky and so not worth releasing at this point. Eventually I'd like to make it into a plugin but that won't be any time soon....